# executeSql() destroys script

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova

i have a little problem with the following javascript. The tx.executeSql() seems to be wrong. When commented out, the script works fine(except of the SQL-part, of course). As soon as i delete the commenting, the whole script does nothing.
Here's my code:

```
function createDb() {

// Datenbank mit allen Tabellen erstellen
var db = window.openDatabase("DBN", "1.0", "DBN", 10000000);
db.transaction(populateRaumbezeichnung, errorCB, successCB);

}

function populateRaumbezeichnung(tx){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "URL",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {

    $.each(json, function(index, result) {
        tx.executeSql('insert into raumbezeichnung values ("'+result.IDRaumbezeichnung+'","'result.Raumbezeichnung'")');
    });
  },
      failure: function(msg) {
         alert("Datenabruf fehlgeschlagen");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: You mean on eclipse? There's no console output.

Comment: Ok, i was able to fix one problem in the parameter of the executeSql(). Now it doesn't destroy the whole script. It also iterates when i comment the executeSql() out. If i don't, it stops the iteration.